# Export/Import folders and files from one Sharepoint site to another

Tags: mirroring

I have seen a few threads/posts that touch on this question, but ***the answers seem to be aimed at SharePoint developers***.  I am not a developer, programmer or coder -- I am a technical writer that needs a (hopefully) reasonably easy way to have the folders, sub-folders and files on my company's SharePoint site *exactly mirror those on a government SharePoint site*. Keep in mind that I am fairly new to SharePoint. I have no problems with the action of uploading files, it's just the issue of simplifying **site-to-site** copying/mirroring.

At the moment, the only way I see to do this in an organized way is to

1.) Create the same folders and sub-folders on my government laptop

2.) Download the files from my company's SP site to the proper folders on the laptop, and then

3.) From my company's SP site, go to each folder/sub-folder and browse the folders on my laptop to upload files.

Please let me know if there is an easier/simpler way -- thanks in advance.

- David G.

Answer (score 0):

Using GUI, you can open Explorer View and make simple drag and drop.

[image]